# Problems retrieving GET requests responses in expected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asynchronous

I'm facing some few problems with my javascript code, as to my understanding probably related to asynchronous functions.

I have some large txt files that I want to import in my javascript code, everything is under the same domain. 
For instance, when I open /index.php I want Javascript to load text from several text files located in: /log/ip_number/log.txt

At the moment I'm using something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfVPS; i++) {
    $.get("/log/"+ip_list[i]+"/log.txt", function(contents){
     //does my things with contents
     array.push(myOutput)
     });
}
```

at the end of the code, I should get an array ordered by the order of IPs in the ip_list array.... but that's not what I get and I can't really understand why...

For example, I should get: 
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

where 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are related the ip_list[0], ip_list[1], ip_list[2], ip_list[3], ip_list[4], 
but I get something like:

array = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4], and everytime I reload the page there is a different order.... 
I think that's due to te fact that the javascript code didn't manage to load the text files and thus give me some unordered output, but that's just my opinion, the opinion of a newbie "programmer"...

Please help me with that!

Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is asynchronous so one of your options is to use [Promise](http://Black.Panther.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM])s
so for example you can write it like :

```
var files = [];
for( var n = 0; n < numberOfVPS; n++ ) {
   files[n] = $.get("FILEPATH");
}
$.when(...files).done(function(){
   array.push(...arguments);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises

Comment: Can't really tell why but

`var files = [];
for( var n = 0; n < numberOfVPS; n++ ) {
   files[n] = $.get("FILEPATH");
}`

seems to works even without `$.when`... 
I resolved using this! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A batch of GET requests doesn't always resolve in the same order they have been triggered.

Instead of pushing the result to the array, you could assign the .txt contents to its corresponding key directly.

```
array[i] = myOutput;
```

But because the value of `i` inside the GET callback, will not longer be the same as when the GET request was executed (counter keeps increasing in the loop) , you need to generate a new scope where the value of `i` is preserved. A `function` would give us that.

You will need also a way to know when the last file has been loaded... to perform you actions...

```
let completed =0;

const getTxt = function(i){
  $.get("/log/"+ip_list[i]+"/log.txt", contents=>{
    array[i] = myOutput;
    completed++
    if(completed === numberOfVPS){ 
      // all files have been loaded 
      yourCallbackHere();
    }
  });
}

for(let i = 0; i < numberOfVPS; i++) getTxt(i)
```

> I personally would implement this using Promises, they are ment to handle Async operations in a more clean and intuitive way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I originally thought about promises but didn't have luck, it's the first time I'm approaching to asynchronous calls... I will do my best to understand promises better!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop makes async calls to load the files. The order will depend on when the callback functions execute having loaded the files. This will depend on the size of the files and network latency.

If you need to have the items in the array sorted you can store an object in the array and use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the objects for ordering after all the callbacks complete.

```
array.push({ index: i, ip: myOutput})

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.index - b.index;
}
```

To get the original array you have use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);

```
array.map(x => x.ip);
```